# Proof that a solution set of a system of equations is a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider the linear system
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
> a_{1,1} &+& \cdots &+& a_{1,n} &=& b_1 \newline
> a_{2,1} &+& \cdots &+& a_{2,n} &=& b_2 \newline
> & & & \vdots & & & \newline
> a_{m,1} &+& \cdots &+& a_{m,n} &=& b_m
> \end{array}
> $$
> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be the set of solutions $\left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \newline \vdots \newline x_n \end{array} \right]$ to the system. Prove that if $\left[ \begin{array}{c} b_1 \newline \vdots \newline b_m \end{array} \right]=0$ then $S$ is a linear subspace,
> and if $\left[ \begin{array}{c} b_1 \newline \vdots \newline b_m \end{array} \right] \neq 0$ then $S$ is not a linear subspace.

I've been stumped on the last part. I understand how to prove $S$ is a linear subspace when all $b=0$, since the set consists of at least the trivial subspace, $S=0$ is a solution, and neither vector addition nor scalar multiplication alters the dimensions of the vector. How would one approach the case where some $b \neq 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just take an example. Say a system of one equation with one unknown: $x=3$.

Comment: Linear subspaces contain the zero vector.